# Does the C++ standard actually guarantee that the operand to a throw expression provides the thrown value?

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, standards, throw

While reading about the details of exception handling in the standard, I noticed that it doesn't ever seem to actually specify that the operand to a throw expression will provide the value for the thrown exception object.

The [expr.throw] section describing the semantics of a throw expression says only that:

> Evaluating a throw-expression with an operand throws **an** exception (15.1); the **type** of the exception object is determined by removing any top-level cv-qualifiers from the static type of the operand and adjusting the type from “array of T” or “function returning T” to “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively.

So if someone says `throw 5`, the type of the exception object must be `int`. This does not seem to actually say that the value of the exception object must be `5` rather than, say, `7` or any other arbitrary value of type `int`. Section 15.1 [except.throw] continues to be just as nebulous. It says things like:

> An object is passed and **the type of that object** determines which handlers can catch it.

Once again, the the type of the operand matters, but not the value of the operand.

> Throwing an exception copy-initializes a temporary object, called the exception object.

A temporary object is copy-initialized, but no mention is made of this temporary object having any particular value. The compiler could copy-initialize the temporary exception object from a prvalue `int` with value `7` if it wanted to, and it would still satisfy this clause because it did copy-initialize a temporary object. *The operand to the throw expression is never mentioned.*

---

So, if I have this program:

```
#include <cassert>
void f() {
    try {
        throw 5;
    } catch (int x) {
        assert(x == 5);
    }
}
```

What specific wording in the C++ standard guarantees that this assertion will never fail? As far as I can tell, the standard only guarantees that the exception object will have type `int` but not that it will have any particular value, i.e. the assertion could fail if the temporary object were initialized with a value of `7`. There doesn't seem to be any mention of the object/value/result of the operand to the throw expression being used to create the exception object.

Comment: You have the answer in your question.  *Throwing an exception copy-initializes a temporary object,* means that the object in the catch block is a copy of what was thrown.  That means it will have the same value unless you do something crazy in the copy constructor, which in this case you can't since it is an int.

Comment: @NathanOliver Where does it say the exception object is copy-initialized **using the value of the operand to the throw expression**? The compiler could copy-initialize the temporary object using any value and you still would have *copy-initialized a temporary object*. My question is where it specifies that this temporary object is copy-initialized from anything in particular.

Comment: I suspect this falls in the "I can't believe we have to specify this" category. There's no room for ambiguity as to which expression provides the source value of the copy-initialization.

Comment: ^ Totally agree @MSalters.  I suppose it could say *Throwing an exception copy-initializes a temporary object from the thrown expression* but to me that is implied.

Comment: I agree that any reasonable person could infer that it should *probably* be copy-initialized *from the operand to the throw expression*, but my curiosity is in the fact that it seems that a compiler would be within its rights to claim to be "100% compliant to the the text of the ISO C++ standard" while also throwing `7` when the expression `throw 5` is used.

Comment: @0x5f3759df, luckily, compiler writers are not lawyers :) on the other hand, while compiler writers might be within their right, such a compiler would sell quite poorly (not that compilers are distributed for free nowadays, but you can substitute sell with any other indication of success).

Comment: @SergeyA Compiler writers are lawyers.